# What did The Witches Cave (Podzemelye Vedm) movie rip off from Highlander?

Tags: highlander, highlander-franchise, the-witches-cave

I saw at least a couple different reviewers mention (in Russian) that the 1990 Soviet movie *[Подземелье ведьм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%BC)* (*[The Witches' Cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Witches_Cave)*) very liberally borrowed from *Highlander*. However none of them went into details.

E.g.

> Много сцен прямо таки содрано с популярного и нашумевшего зарубежного "Горца", вышедшего несколькими годами ранее. (*source: http://otzovik.com/review_1571181.html*)
>
> A lot of scenes have been ripped off from the popular and famous foreign film *Highlander*, released several years earlier.

Is there a detailed explanation of what exactly *The Witches' Cave* did rip off from *Highlander*?

Answer (score 4):

Having glanced through Подземелье Ведьм (AKA Podzemelye Vedm AKA The Witches Cave) it's obvious that the [start sequence](https://youtu.be/xJ__j31z3io?t=88) (a sort of framing story for the rest of the film) has been taken almost shot-for-shot from the [opening battle sequence from Highlander](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yvyXxBOgVg&feature=youtu.be&t=195).

The [fight scene at the very end of the film](https://youtu.be/xJ__j31z3io?t=4087) also shares *some* similarity with [Connor's climactic fight with the Kurgan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_j6_H-PSml0) (as well as some [walking underwater with a sword](https://youtu.be/xJ__j31z3io?t=4131) elements that seem vaguely reminiscent of [Connor's training with Ramirez](https://youtu.be/BUPGVvtmV84?t=111)) but I'd hardly describe *the whole film* as a shameless ripoff, just the opening.

Answer (score 3):

I watched the *The Witches' Cave* (with the sound off and while I was doing something else, but keeping it in view out of the corner of my eye).  There were not a ton of similarities, but there certainly was this guy:

[image: Villain with Skull Helm]

With his heavy sword and fanged skull for a helm, he bears more than a passing resemblance to the Kurgan from *Highlander*,

[image: The Kurgan]

Both characters show up right near the beginnings of their films, for a tone-setting battle scene.

Moreover, another villainous thug bears a significant resemblance to Clancy Brown, the actor who played the Kurgan.  One of the things that made the Kurgan appear so menacing was Brown's unusual appearance, with a particularly broad, flat face.  Here is another image of him, this one from in *Starship Troopers*.

[image: Clancy Brown]

*The Witches' Cave* also features another important villain, who looks like he was chosen particularly for his similarity in appearance to Brown (who also had no hair on his head through most of *Highlander*).

[image: Lookalike]